# How to understand Memory dump from windbg?

Tags: windbg

One of our website is using like 2gb memories, and we are trying to understand why it is using so much (as we are trying to push this site to azure, as big memory usage means higher bill from azure).

I took an IIS dump and from task manager, I can see it was using like 2.2GB momory.
Then I run `!address -summary`and this is what I got:

```
--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                    913      7fb`2f5ce000 (   7.981 Tb)           99.76%
<unknown>                              4055        4`a49c9000 (  18.572 Gb)  96.43%    0.23%
Heap                                    338        0`1dbd1000 ( 475.816 Mb)   2.41%    0.01%
Image                                  3147        0`0c510000 ( 197.063 Mb)   1.00%    0.00%
Stack                                   184        0`01d40000 (  29.250 Mb)   0.15%    0.00%
Other                                    14        0`001bf000 (   1.746 Mb)   0.01%    0.00%
TEB                                      60        0`00078000 ( 480.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Type Summary (for busy) ------ RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_PRIVATE                            2206        4`ba7d2000 (  18.914 Gb)  98.20%    0.23%
MEM_IMAGE                              5522        0`148b0000 ( 328.688 Mb)   1.67%    0.00%
MEM_MAPPED                               71        0`019a0000 (  25.625 Mb)   0.13%    0.00%

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                913      7fb`2f5ce000 (   7.981 Tb)           99.76%
MEM_RESERVE                            2711        4`378f4000 (  16.868 Gb)  87.58%    0.21%
MEM_COMMIT                             5088        0`9912e000 (   2.392 Gb)  12.42%    0.03%

--- Protect Summary (for commit) - RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
PAGE_READWRITE                         1544        0`81afb000 (   2.026 Gb)  10.52%    0.02%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ                       794        0`0f35d000 ( 243.363 Mb)   1.23%    0.00%
PAGE_READONLY                          2316        0`05ea8000 (  94.656 Mb)   0.48%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE                  279        0`020f4000 (  32.953 Mb)   0.17%    0.00%
PAGE_WRITECOPY                           92        0`0024f000 (   2.309 Mb)   0.01%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_GUARD                61        0`000e6000 ( 920.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE                              2        0`00005000 (  20.000 kb)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
Free                                      5`3fac0000      7f9`59610000 (   7.974 Tb)
<unknown>                                 3`06a59000        0`f9067000 (   3.891 Gb)
Heap                                      0`0f1c0000        0`00fd0000 (  15.813 Mb)
Image                                   7fe`fe767000        0`007ad000 (   7.676 Mb)
Stack                                     0`01080000        0`0007b000 ( 492.000 kb)
Other                                     0`00880000        0`00183000 (   1.512 Mb)
TEB                                     7ff`ffe44000        0`00002000 (   8.000 kb)
PEB                                     7ff`fffdd000        0`00001000 (   4.000 kb)
```

There are lots of things I don't really get:

1. The webserver has 8GB memory in total, but the Free section in the Usage summary is showing 7.9Tb? Why?
2. Unknown was showing 19.572GB, but the webserver has 8GB memory in total. Why?
3. The task manager shows private memory workset was like 2.2GB, but if I add Heap, Image and Stack together it is only around 700MB, so where are the rest 1.5 GB memory or I totally read the output wrong?

Many Thanks

Comment: 64Bit apps have 8TB of virtual memory til win8, later versions 128TB, that why you see this large number. Use [DebugDiag2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) Analyzer to analyze dmp  for memory usage, it is easier compared to windbg

Comment: Thanks, I understand that now. Also the 1.5GB can be found in manged heap -gc.

Answer (score 0):

> The webserver has 8GB memory in total, but the Free section in the Usage summary is showing 7.9Tb? Why?

The 8 GB RAM is physical memory, i.e. the one that's filled in the DDR slots of your PC. The 8 TB is virtual memory, which could also be stored in the page file.

The virtual memory can be 4 GB for a 32 bit process and depends on the exact limitations of the OS for 64 bit processes.

> Unknown was showing 19.572GB, but the webserver has 8GB memory in total. Why?

The 19 GB is amount the virtual memory used by an `<unknown>` memory manager, e.g. .NET or direct calls to `VirtualAlloc()`.

Even if 19 GB is more than 8 GB, this does not necessarily mean that memory was swapped to disk. It depends on the state of the memory. Looking at `MEM_RESERVE`, we see that most of it is not in use yet. Therefore, your application may still have good performance.

> The task manager shows private memory workset was like 2.2GB, but if I add Heap, Image and Stack together it is only around 700MB, so where are the rest 1.5 GB memory or I totally read the output wrong?

The rest is in `<unknown>`, so the sum is even more than 2.2 GB shown by task manager. The working set size indicates how much physical RAM is used by your process. Ideally, everything would be in RAM, since RAM is the fastest. But RAM is limited and not all applications will fit into RAM. Therefore, memory that is not used very often is swapped to disk, which decreases the use of physical RAM and thus decreases the working set size.